# Using reaver (for wifi hacking) on Ubuntu 20 issue

Tags: networking, airmon-ng

I am trying to find out(to hack) my wifi password, just for fun and learn something new :) . I followed the [tutorial](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/07/learn-to-hack-wifi-password-with-ubuntu.html):

And this is how far I got:

1. This is the result of my `iwconfig`:

   lo        no wireless extensions.

   wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TP-Link"
   Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: D8:07:B6:86:86:1F
   Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=23 dBm
   Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
   Power Management:off
   Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm
   Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
   Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:62   Missed beacon:0
2. After I run:

   sudo airmon-ng start wlp2s0
   and I got this:

   Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
   Kill them using 'airmon-ng check kill' before putting
   the card in monitor mode, they will interfere by changing channels
   and sometimes putting the interface back in managed mode

   ```
    PID Name
    765 avahi-daemon
    774 NetworkManager
    806 wpa_supplicant
    810 avahi-daemon
   ```

   PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

   phy0    wlp2s0      ath10k_pci  Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)

   ```
        (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlp2s0 on [phy0]wlp2s0mon)
        (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlp2s0)
   ```
3. After I killed all of the processes with:

   `sudo airmon-ng check kill`
4. And finally I run: `sudo airodump-ng wlp2s0mon` to get the list of wifi networks and I got this:
   [image]

My expectations would be to get some BSSID s.

The final step would be to run  `reaver -i wlp2s0mon -b {BSSID value}`. Would you please let me know what I did wrong or what should I do next, so I can continue my study? Thank you

Comment: would you please tell me , why this question is down voted ? If it is not clear , i will edit my post .

Comment: I have no experience with `airmon-ng`, but from a bit of reading, did you try running `sudo airmon-ng start wlp2s0` again after you ran `sudo airmon-ng check kill`? Also, did `sudo airmon-ng check kill` provide any output?

Comment: @PixelatedFish yes, it killed the processes, and I lost the wifi internet connection. I believe that is expected.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is possible that your wifi adapter does not support monitor mode, if he is, those commands should work out.

   - for monitor mode (run with sudo or as root):

```
ip link set wlp2s0 down
systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service
systemctl mask wpa_supplicant.service
iw dev wlp2s0 set type monitor
```

2. now you can run your airodump commands, for a test run:

```
airodump-ng wlp2s0
```

3. to get your wifi interface back to managed mode you can run this commands (run with sudo or as root):

```
ip link set wlp2s0 down
systemctl umask wpa_supplicant.service
systemctl start wpa_supplicant.service
iw dev wlp2s0 set type managed
ip link set wlp2s0 up
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service #only if wifi connection does not came back alone.
```

**I build those two scripts to switch between monitor and manage mode:**

- **managed.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#Run As Root

echo "please enter a interface: "

read interface

ip link set dev $interface down

systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service

systemctl unmask wpa_supplicant.service

systemctl start wpa_supplicant.service

iw dev $interface set type managed

ip link set dev $interface up
```

- **monitor.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#Run As Root

echo "please enter a interface: "

read interface

ip link set dev $interface down

systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service

systemctl mask wpa_supplicant.service

iw dev $interface set type monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that Wi-Fi Card, which is build-in in your laptop, cannot work in a monitor mode. So you have to buy an extra Wi-Fi adapter.